# Why isn't electric field null at the midpoint of a straight line connecting two opposite charges of same magnitude?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

**I am confused why the value of the electric field is not null in the midpoint of a dipole as Charge q(A) attracts a negative test charge with the same force of charge q(B) repelling the test charge. Shouldn't they both cancel each other out?  **

Comment: Because they are opposite charges, so the E-field generated by each charge points in opposite directions.  Your vision would be accurate if both charges were the same polarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your short circuit assumption is probably "attraction + repulsion = cancels out". But if you think more carefully, you notice that since attraction and repulsion come from opposite sides of the test charge, they are actually acting in the same direction.

Imagine your mother on the right side, pushing you out of the house, and your friend on the left side, pulling you out of the house - will you stay at the sill?

Comment: I am sorry, but your interpretation of what's the purpose of an answer is obviously not congruent with mine. Sometimes people get stuck, and as long as it is not a troll question, I am fine with answers to it. But if you are arrogant enough, it is always possible to put somebody down.